# MySQL tables relationship and the use of md5 hash

Tags: mysql, hash, md5, relationship

I have a MySQL DB with 2 tables:

- sample_name (stores name of a file, multiple names for same sample_hash);
- sample_hash (stores the hashes of a file, will not store duplicate md5);

(all tables have an `id` int unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment)

My first option to relate these two tables is by creating an md5 column in both tables and relate them. However this seems to have a downside as I will be duplicating a varchar(32), which can be a waste of space with millions of records.

My second option is to calculate the file hashes first, grab the `mysql_insert_id()` of the sample_hash table and insert into the sample_name table. This makes sense if the hash in the sample_hash table is new, thus I have the `mysql_insert_id()` variable at my disposal.

But if the hash already exist in the samples_db, I don't want to store the hash again, so I will have no `mysql_insert_id()`.

Is there an alternative other than searching the id of a given md5 in order to store it in the samples_name table in case the md5 already exist? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: Can you refactor to store the file name and hash in the same table?

Comment: I'm familiarized with refactoring. How does the process work?

Comment: I don't know exactly how you can do that, however do you already have all your fields optimized? I'm thinking of an unique index for the hash on `sample_hash`, and a simple index for the other table. Field should be of type char(32). If you don't find any solution to avoid the search, a least this way it will be a bit faster

Comment: @karamazov, does that answer your question, or do you have other concerns or reservations?

Answer (score 1):

From the requirements that you describe, there is no need for the sample_hash table at all.

You can keep the hashes in the sample_name table and do all your lookups of hash values in that table.

Comment: I need to keep both filenames and hashes on separated tables because one hash can have multiple filenames. In the meanwhile i've indexed the md5 collumn, probably is the best option.